# Monads in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, theory, monads

How would an example JavaScript code look like that uses Monad? I'm asking because understanding Monad is much clearer if I can see a code example (and JavaScript being a simple, functional language it could be the best language to use to learn it).

Comment: Tell something about Monad, how it is diff from javascript ?

Comment: @Umesh - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)

Comment: JQuery is pretty much a monad in js.

Comment: I suppose, code "*using* Monads" is the same as in other languages. For better understanding I'd better look into writing monads. Also, just google: "monads javascript". There're a bunch of articles.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would start by writing your own monad in JavaScript.  The list monad is a great place to start; I find it by far the most useful.  Simply define functions which do the following:

1. Create a list of one given item (call this `mreturn`).
2. Create an empty list (call this `mzero`).
3. Append one list to another (call this `mplus`).
4. Apply a function to transform every element in a given list (call this `map`).
5. "Flatten" a list of lists into a simple list by concatenating the lists (call this `join`).

This defines what's known as an "additive monad" (`mzero` and `mplus` form the "additive" part).  Play around to see what interesting things you can do *using only these functions* to operate on lists.  For example, you can compute the list of all even numbers on a schoolkid's multiplication table like so:

```
var nums = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ];
var even_products = join(map(join(map(nums, function (x) {
        return map(nums, function(y) { return x * y })
    })),
    function (x) { if (x % 2 == 0) { return mreturn(x) } else { return mzero() } }
));
```

Alternatively, combine `map` and `join` together as a single function defined as `function bind(l, f) { return join(map(l, f)) }`.  `bind` can be used instead of `map` and `join` and is used more often in e.g. Haskell.  The same exercise above can then be written:

```
var nums = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ];
var even_products = bind(
    bind(nums, function (x) {
        return bind(nums, function (y) { return mreturn(x * y) })
    }),
    function (x) { if (x % 2 == 0) { return mreturn(x) } else { return mzero() } }
);
```

Finally, you may want to incorporate these functions as part of a new list prototype (or whatever JavaScript has that passes for classes these days), so you can instead write the jQuery-esque:

```
var nums = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ];
var even_products = nums
    .bind(function (x) { return nums.bind(function (y) { return mreturn(x * y) }) })
    .bind(function (x) { if (x % 2 == 0) { return mreturn(x) } else { return mzero() } });
```